# Configure window firewall option in window 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

My firewall setting says that

```
Display notification when program is blocked  -- NO
```

I want to make that yes but could not find anywhere in firewall settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947788%28WS.10%29.aspx#bkmk_ToenableWindowsFirewallandconfigurethedefaultbehavior

## ---Make this YES instead

Under Firewall settings, change Display a notification to **No**.

Comment: thanks buddy it worked . I don't have any group policy but it was under local policy